# mxd.saveACopy not creating a second copy

Tags: arcpy

I am having an issue with my script not wanting to create a second copy of a `mxd`. The error that I am given states that...

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 95, in <module>
NameError: name 'mxd' is not defined
```

making line 95 the last `mxd.saveACopy`. Any thoughts to correct it? I am lost because my `mxd` is being referenced in the beginning.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)"
from arcpy import da #this will allow access to the data access module
from arcpy import mapping # Mapping Module
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Open a map document (shell document)
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/mxd files/Project.mxd")

#Setting Dataframes
first_df = mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Merging data procresses

#file output for Project active Rigs
file_output1 = "C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/Shapefiles/rig_exampleRigsDIShape.shp"
file_output2 = "C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Active_Rigs"


for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
        dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)

        if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
            print('skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: ' + file_output1)
        else:
            # Determine the new output feature class path and name
            outfc = os.path.join(file_output2, file_output1)

            # Set output coordinate system
            outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1927 StatePlane Texas Central FIPS 4203')

            # run project tool
            arcpy.Project_management(file_output1, file_output2, outCS)

            # check messages
            print(arcpy.GetMessages())


# Layer to be added to the data frame
layer = mapping.Layer("C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Active_Rigs")
# Change the name of the layer before adding
layer.name = "Rigs Locations"
# Add the layer at the top of the data frame
mapping.AddLayer(first_df,layer,"TOP")

mxd.saveACopy("C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/mxd files/Active Rigs map.mxd")

del mxd
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GeoProcess: Merge Permitted :: Project:: instert Permitted Bottom Hole Locations
#file locations
file_output3 = "C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/scratch.gdb/Merged_Permit_points"
file_output4 = "C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Permitted_Locations"

#Merge Process
NmPt_data = "NewMexicoPermitsDIShape_BottomLocation.shp"
TxPt_data = "txPermitsDIShape_BottomLocation.shp"
fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
# Add all fields from both New Mexico data and Texas data
fieldMappings.addTable(NmPt_data)
fieldMappings.addTable(TxPt_data)
arcpy.Merge_management([NmPt_data, TxPt_data], file_output3, fieldMappings)


for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
        dsc = arcpy.Describe(file_output3)

        if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
            print('skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: ' + file_output3)
        else:
            # Determine the new output feature class path and name
            outfc = os.path.join(file_output4, file_output3)

            # Set output coordinate system
            outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1927 StatePlane Texas Central FIPS 4203')

            # run project tool
            arcpy.Project_management(file_output3, file_output4, outCS)

            # check messages
            print(arcpy.GetMessages())


# Layer to be added to the data frame
layer = mapping.Layer("C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/New File Geodatabase.gdb/Permitted_Locations")
# Change the name of the layer before adding
layer.name = "Permitted Locations"
# Add the layer at the top of the data frame
mapping.AddLayer(first_df,layer,"TOP")

mxd.saveACopy("C:/Users/JLandolt/Desktop/New folder (2)/mxd files/Permit map.mxd")

del mxd
```

Comment: You have a `del mxd` above the second `mxd.saveACopy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is correctly stating that the MXD doesn't exist.

You create the `mxd` on line 8.
On line 48 you saveacopy and then on line 50 you `del mxd`. 
You then go through another merge process and on line 95 you try to `mxd.saveACopy`, but you deleted it on line 50.

So you either need to NOT delete it, or create a new copy of it the same as line 8.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It really helped out.